# How to adjust kerning for the unicode flat symbol

Tags: html, vue.js, unicode

I'm trying to describe a chord, B♭, but it is showing up weird in an `<option>` HTML tag. Instead of "B♭", it shows up with an apparent space between the "B" and the "♭".

I tried applying a CSS style, `letter-spacing`, to this chord in a `<span>` tag, but apparently, this doesn't control kerning.

Interestingly, when I select the chord from the dropdown, my OS renders the kerning correctly, but after it is selected, the flat symbol shows up by itself, set aside by a space, like the following.

[image: unusual kerning between a letter and a flat symbol]

The JS literal that I'm trying to render is,

```
'B\u266D'
```

Using the literal `'B&flat;'` just renders as `'B&flat;'` in the dropdown.

FWIW, I'm doing this from within Vue3, and looking at the output in Chrome, on a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a rendering issue in Chrome 96 on macOS (and possibly other Chromium-based browsers and other operating systems). Firefox 91 on macOS [renders it correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4zTp.jpg). The problem also only affects the *flat* (`\u266d`) and *natural* (`\u266e`) signs. The *sharp*, *double sharp*, and *double flat* signs are unaffected in my tests.

You could workaround the issue by adjusting the `<select>`'s `letter-spacing` with a negative value (to bring the characters closer together, thus reducing the gap), and compensating for the reduced width with `padding` on the right. You'd only want to do this conditionally for the affected signs, so use a computed prop that returns the necessary `letter-spacing` and `padding`:

1. Use a [`v-model`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-model) on the `<select>` to capture the selected note.
2. Use a [computed prop](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#computed-values) that returns the styles needed to adjust `letter-spacing` and `padding`. When the selected note contains the problematic signs, return the adjusted spacing/padding.
3. Bind the computed style to the `<select>`'s styles.

```html
<script setup>
const notes = [
  'B\u266d', // flat
  'B\u266e', // natural
  'B\u266f', // sharp
  'B\u{1D12B}', // double flat
  'B\u{1D12A}', // double sharp
]
1️⃣
let selectedNote = $ref(notes[0])

2️⃣
let styles = $computed(() => {
  if (selectedNote.includes('\u266d') || selectedNote.includes('\u266e')) {
    return {
      'letter-spacing': '-20px',
      'padding-right': '40px',
    }
  }
})
</script>

<template>
  <select 1️⃣ v-model="selectedNote" :style="styles" 3️⃣>
    <option v-for="note in notes">{{ note }}</option>
  </select>
</template>
```

***Note:** The `<script setup>` above uses the new/experimental [*Reactivity Transform*](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/369), which supports globally defined reactivity APIs (`$ref`, `$computed`, etc.) and removes the need to unwrap `ref`s.*

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-workaround-select-render-bug?file=src/components/MusicalNotesDropdown.vue)

*Result on Chrome 96 on macOS:*

[image]